# Como crear una ventana modal a partir de un js

Tags: javascript, java, spring

Como se podría crear una ventana modal a partir la respuesta de un ajax, la respuesta del ajax me devuelve el HTML que quiero imprimir en una ventana modal

formulario

```
<form id="formAddEgre" class="labels-center" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                            <div class="row">               
                                <div class="row ">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="selecArchivo" class="control-label col-md-3">   Seleccionar Archivo</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9" id="div-inputfile" >
                                                <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput"> 
                                                    <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"> 
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> 
                                                        <span class="fileinput-filename"></span> 
                                                    </div> 
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file"> 
                                                        <span class="fileinput-new">Seleccionar archivo</span> 
                                                        <span class="fileinput-exists">Cambiar</span> 
                                                        <input type="file" name="selecArchivo"  id="selecArchivo" required="" /> 
                                                    </span> 
                                                    <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remover</a> 
                                                </div>
                                                <label id="mensajeError" style="color: red; display:none;">*Se requiere un archivo excel con extenci&oacute;n XLSX*</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float: right;">     
                                    <button type="submit" id="btnAgregarEgre" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnAgregarEgre" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Subir">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

De ese formulario se activa el codigo javascript con la peticion ajax

```
    $("#formAddEgre").submit(function (e) {
        //obtenemos la extencion del archivo
        var ext=$("#selecArchivo").val().split(".");
        console.log(ext);
        //validamos que sea XlsX
        if(ext[1]=="xlsx"){
            //se oculta el mensaje deerror 
            $("#mensajeError").css("display","none");
            //esto evita que se haga la petición común, es decir evita que se refresque la pagina
            e.preventDefault();

            //ruta la cual recibira nuestro archivo
            url="egresadosPlus/leerExcel"

            //FormData es necesario para el envio de archivo,
            //y de la siguiente manera capturamos todos los elementos del formulario
            var data = new FormData();
            jQuery.each($('input[type=file]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                data.append('file-'+i, file);
                console.log('file-'+i, file);
            });

            var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();
            $.each(other_data,function(key,input){
                data.append(input.name,input.value);
            });

            //realizamos la petición ajax con la función de jquery
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                contentType: false, //importante enviar este parametro en false
                processData: false, //importante enviar este parametro en false
                success: function (data) {

                   alert(data)
                },
                error: function (r) {

                    alert("Error del servidor");
                }
            });
                //mostramos el gif de cargando
                animateLoader(true);
                return true;
            }else{
                //se muestra el mensaje de error por si el formato es diferente
                $("#mensajeError").css("display","block");
                return false;
            }
    })
```

la peticion ajax me manda a un codigo de java, estoy utilizando el framework de spring para recibir el archivo de tipo file el cual me lee el excel y me regresa a una pagina, lo que me gustaria saber es si a partir del codigo que me regresa, se podria mostrar dentro de un modal
[image: Ese es el resultado que me devuelme mi clase en java]

Esa es la clase java que tengo

```
@RequestMapping(value="/leerExcel", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String leerExcel(@RequestParam("file-0") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
        try {

            /*Inicia codigo para leer el archivo */
            /*
             * Se imprime el nombre del archivo que se esta enviando, 
             * Traemos la ruta donde se copiaran los archivos
             * Optenemos el nombre del archivo sin extension
             * subimos el archivo al servidor y se copia a la ruta especificada*/
            PathsEnum path =PathsEnum.ADD_EGRESADOS_EXCEL; 
            String nombreSinExt=FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            fileService.uploadFile(file,nombreSinExt, config.getValue( path.getValue()));

            /*
             * Leer archivo excel asignamos la ruta del archivo a la variable rutaArchivoExcel
             * acepta archivos solo con la extension XLSX
             * URL: http://www.decodigo.com/java-leer-archivo-excel
             * */
            String rutaArchivoExcel = "mi ruta;
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(rutaArchivoExcel));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
            ArrayList<Egresado> existen=new ArrayList();
            ArrayList<String> noexisten=new ArrayList();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = (Row) iterator.next();
                Iterator cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                String contenidoCelda="";
                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = (Cell) cellIterator.next();
                     contenidoCelda += formatter.formatCellValue(cell)+"  ";
                }
                System.out.println("No_cuenta :"+contenidoCelda);
                String azul[]=contenidoCelda.split("  ");
                if(!azul[0].equals("CUENTA")) {
                    //obtiene la informacion del usuario por numero de cuenta
                    Egresado egresa=egresadoPlusService.getUsuarioCuenta(azul[0]);
                    if(egresa != null) {                    
                        existen.add(egresa);                    
                    }else {
                        noexisten.add(contenidoCelda);
                    }
                }
            }
            model.addAttribute("existen",existen);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Egresados/duplicadosTabla";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno explico la respuesta, primero tienes que cargar los datos que llegan de la respuesta `ajax` y guardarlos en una variable.

Tienes que crear el modal en el `html` con un contenedor en este ejemplo seria un `div` con el **`id="idInfoAjax"`** en el cual voy a pintar el `html`.

Ahora en **`Js`** al id le seteas el `html`, al dar clic en el **`btn`** se abre el **modal** con la información que llega.

Revisa este **Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const htmlAjax = '<table class="table table-condensed table-hover"><thead><tr class="info"><th>ID Egregado</ht><th>Nombre</ht><th>Correo</ht><th>Carrera</ht><th>Ingreso</ht></tr></thead></tbody></table>'
 
  $("#idInfoAjax").html(htmlAjax);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="idInfoAjax">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudo mucho